# Connect CitusData with PHP/Laravel

Tags: docker, citus

I have followed the instructions to setup the CitusData Single Cluster using Docker.

When I try to use this with Laravel then this does not work and this throws for Connection Refused.

Any idea to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I do not have experience on Laravel, but here is an idea: Make sure that you are using the TCP socket and *not* the Unix domain socket.

The TCP port (5432 by default) is exposed on the container but not the Unix domain socket. When running the database and the application on the same instance, your application may be trying to use the Unix domain socket because:

- it is slightly advantageous to use the Unix Domain Sockets as they do not need the three-way handshakes
- and they are slightly faster because of this